# How can I attach a garden hose to my sink faucet?

Tags: faucet, sink

I would like to attach a garden-hose adapter to my sink faucet. Currently there is an aerator on the end that I like.

Is there some solution that anyone knows of that will allow both the garden hose adapter and aerator to function simultaneously on the faucet. I just don't want to have to attach the adapter each time I use a hose.

I was thinking either an adapter with an aerator built in, or an adapter with aerator threads on the inside of the hose end. Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you require the hose end to have tempered water, or is cold water only okay?

Comment: I'll be using it mostly for filling my turtle tank, so the water should be around 75-80°F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
This is an aerator with male garden hose thread. If your local mom-and-pop hardware or plumbing store does not have it, have them order one for you. Don't even try a "big-box" store... fuggetaboutit

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.lasco.net/index.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=7831

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I tried looking yesterday at my local Lowes however finding nothing was what led me to ask here.

Comment: I'm new to the area, however I found a True Value and a couple other smaller hardware stores which I'll try today.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it won't be pretty. There's a fitting designed to let you hook up a dishwasher to a sink faucet. They come in both temporary and permanent varieties. Don't ignore the removable kind as that might be exactly what you need if your hose use is just occasional. From there, you can get another fitting to step up the dishwasher connection to a garden hose size connection.

Just realize that you're not going to get much volume/pressure out of a sink.

If you don't need a garden hose per-se but just a hose-like think for short range use, investigate a bath store like Bed Bath and Beyond. There exist rubber hand-held shower products that are designed to fit on to the end of a bath spout or screw on to a sink.

Comment: Thanks longneck. I don't think the dishwasher fitting is what I want, however the bath/sink hose idea may work for me. I just need about 6-8 feet to go from my sink to my turtle tank for when it gets low.